# UIActionSheet will not respond to touches when shown

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am writing a mobile app in MonoTouch. One of my ViewControllers is a settings page that allows the users to set a few things that they can customize on their map view. One of these is the Pin color. I have 12 colors of pins and decided to use a UIPickerView to present the choices. The client wants the user to have to tap a "Done" button when they find the color they want. For this I have created a UIToolBar and put a cancel and a done button on it. The tool bar is shown directly above the UIPickerView. I put the PickerView and the Toolbar on a UIActionSheet and display the ActionSheet when the user taps into the PinColor text field.

All of this works, up to this point. When the user clicks on the pin color text field, the action sheet appears and the picker view and toolbar are visible and where they are expected to be. The problem is, I can not interact with either of the buttons or the picker view. It's like there's a viewcontroller in front of the action sheet, but I can not see anywhere that I am doing that. Can someone please take a look at the following code and let me know if you see something? This is just a section of my viewcontroller's code so there may be something missing. However, my code is complete and it compiles fine.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    tmpRect = new RectangleF(0,-220,this.View.Bounds.Width,220);
    myActionSheet = new UIActionSheet(tmpRect);
    myActionSheet.Style = UIActionSheetStyle.Default;
    myActionSheet.DestructiveButtonIndex = 0;
    myActionSheet.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0,true);
    settingsScrollView.AddSubview(myActionSheet);

    tmpRect = new RectangleF(0,-220,this.View.Bounds.Width,40);
    myToolbar = new UIToolbar(tmpRect);
    myToolbar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
    myToolbar.Translucent = true;
    myToolbar.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    myToolbar.SizeToFit();

    UIBarButtonItem btnLeft = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, PickerButtonCancelHandler);
    UIBarButtonItem btnFlexibleSpace = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, null);
    UIBarButtonItem btnDone = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, PickerButtonDoneHandler);
    UIBarButtonItem[] items = new UIBarButtonItem[] { btnLeft, btnFlexibleSpace, btnDone }; 
    myToolbar.SetItems(items, true);
    myActionSheet.AddSubview(myToolbar);

    tmpRect = new RectangleF(0,-176, this.View.Bounds.Width,200);
    pvPinColor = new UIPickerView(tmpRect);
    MyPicker _pinPicker = new MyPicker();
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Azure");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Black");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Blue");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Chartreuse");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Green");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Grey");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Orange");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Pink");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Red");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Violet");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("White");
    _pinPicker.Items.Add("Yellow");
    pvPinColor.Source = _pinPicker;
    pvPinColor.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    pvPinColor.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;
    myActionSheet.AddSubview(pvPinColor);
    settingsScrollView.AddSubview(txtPinColor);

    txtPinColor.EditingDidBegin += delegate {
        txtPinColor.ResignFirstResponder();
        txtPinColor.InputView = pvPinColor;
        myActionSheet.ShowInView(settingsScrollView);
        myActionSheet.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        myActionSheet.BecomeFirstResponder();
        settingsScrollView.BringSubviewToFront(myActionSheet);

        _pinPicker.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
            if (File.Exists (pinFilePath)) { File.Delete(pinFilePath); }
            File.WriteAllText(pinFilePath, _pinPicker.SelectedItem);
            txtPinColor.Text = _pinPicker.SelectedItem;
            //pvPinColor.Hidden = true;
        };
    };
       }

public class MyPicker : UIPickerViewModel
{
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;

public List<string> Items
{
    get { return this._items;} 
    set { this._items = value;}
}
List<string> _items = new List<string>();

public string SelectedItem
{
    get { return this._items[this._selectedIndex]; }
}
protected int _selectedIndex = 0;

public MyPicker()
{   
}

public override int GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView picker, int component)
{
    return this._items.Count;
}

public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
{
    return this._items[row];
}

public override int GetComponentCount (UIPickerView picker)
{
    return 1;
}

public override void Selected (UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
{
    this._selectedIndex = row;
      if (this.ValueChanged != null)
      {
        this.ValueChanged (this, new EventArgs());
   }
}
}
```